# AJAX $(document).ready(function() not executing on page load... sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am not quite sure what I should think about my issue so I am putting it out there so maybe somebody can help me.

I have an jQuery request executing at the load of the page with `$(document).ready(function(){});`. This request worked, lets say, for a week and now it does not work anymore... I tried EVERYTHING to get that back working. The request loaded some content for a page. I have the same file on another computer, and it executes an `alert()` subfunction perfectly. WTF??? I put all these AJAX functions into a JS file. There was a second AJAX request in that file that is executed upon a button click `$("#AdmConUserCreate").click(function(){`. This function works on my first computer perfectly but not on the second one. I do not understand, why a function works on one computer but not on another. this is why I hate JS as I experienced inconsistencies in the execution of code before but I cannot realize my project without it. 
Is there a certain sequence I have to put the code in the file? What am I missing? I am really running out of options here... This is so frustrating. Please see the code of my JS File below:

```
var check = function(PW1,PW2,PWCheck) {
    if (document.getElementById(PW1).value == document.getElementById(PW2).value) {
        document.getElementById(PWCheck).src = 'pwdright.png';
        document.getElementById(PWCheck).width = "10px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById(PWCheck).src = 'pwdwrong.png';
        document.getElementById(PWCheck).width = "10px";
    }
}

function openNav(evt, section) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(section).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function provideFeedback() {
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){
        x.className = x.className.replace("show","");
    }, 3000);   
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.txt",
        success: function(result){
            document.getElementById("DbInfo").innerHTML = result;
        },
        error: function(result){
            document.getElementById("DbInfo").innerHTML = "Here should be the table";
            document.getElementById("snackbar").innerHTML = "doesn't work";
            provideFeedback();
        }
    });    
});

$("#AdmConUserCreate").click(function(){
    alert("Hello");
});
```

BTW  the first three functions work PERFECTLY FINE everywhere.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have any error in the JavaScript console? (`ctrl + shift + j` with Firefox)

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" - Do you see any errors in the console? Do you see the the ajax execute, but it doesn't return any value? We need more details

Comment: Browser cache?!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: F12 in Google Chrome as well.

Comment: try by adding `$("#AdmConUserCreate").click(function(){
    alert("Hello");
});` inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: If it's working on another browser then it obviously is an issue with your current browser. Have you tried clearing your cache on the browser and reloading the web page?

Comment: It is possible you don't have jQuery? I know it's a stupid question, but still...

Comment: You're going to want to add your click handlers inside your document.ready function, depending on where your JS is being loaded.

Comment: The only two errors I get is that one picture cannot be loaded which is fine and I know the reason. The other one is 'jquery-3.2.1.js:9566 Failed to load file:///PATH/protected/test.txt: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
send @ jquery-3.2.1.js:9566'

Comment: @VipinKumar: Your suggestions works. Do you have an explanation WHY???

Comment: @mhodges Thanks that works. WHY can I not have that after the document  ready function?

Comment: @realShadow document.ready function waits for the DOM to be fully loaded before invoking the JavaScript defined in its callback. If you load your JS in your <head> or above your html in the <body> and do not put click handlers inside your document ready function, `$(".selector")` will return 0 elements because the DOM has not been loaded yet, and then register a click event on no elements. The solutions include: load your JS at the very bottom of your <body>, or use a document ready function.

Comment: @mhodges: Thanks for the explanation. This helps understanding that whole thing a little better. I will try the two ways you described and figure out the way that works best for me.

Comment: Added in answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `button` event handler inside `$(document).ready(function(){})`. Like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#AdmConUserCreate").click(function(){
      alert("Hello");
  });
})
```

In your current code, it is possible that when your javascript is getting executed at that time your `DOM` is not completly loaded. `$(document).ready` ensures that your `DOM` is ready and you can start writing code that includes `DOM` manipulations.

Link: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I made a f...ing silly mistake and did not immediately see it. I copied some code through the shell/terminal window and did not see that it cut off one AJAX command. That lead my whole code to basically not work at all anymore. Finally found it after an hour of search. Stupid Stupid Stupid mistake. **THANKS FOR YOUR PATIENCE AND HELP**